# Get Users Email Address from SAMaccount

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am new to powershell, but actually I need a script so I started to read myself into this stuff and found powershell.

I have a username list like:

- xyxz
- domainname\xyxz.xyxc

This script should search all the samaccountname from my userlist and give me the email adresses for every samaccountname.

Get-Content C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Users.txt | forEach {
    Get-ADUser "I dont Know how to specify the username" | select mail | Export-Csv output.csv
}

This is the script I was writing know, but I don't know how to finish it to get it work. I know it is not well done but I don't wanted to write some text here without doing something myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were kind of close

```
Get-Content C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Users.txt | forEach { Get-ADUser $_ -properties EmailAddress} | select -ExpandProperty EmailAddress | Out-File output.csv
```

should do the trick (if your txt file contains the samid, and only one per line).

You can access objects inside the pipeline by using `$_`. Also to get the String value of a property with select you have to use `-ExpandProperty`.

In this case you also have to select the property (EmailAddress) specifically since only a limited set of properties is reported back by default to reduce workload (this is done by specifying the `-properties` Parameter.

Comment: Working fine can i ask u something more? I would like to test the Users.txt so whenever there is a domain like xx-xx\abc it should trimm it. So at the end there would be only abc without the xx-xx\.

Comment: @timo here is an article that should help you do it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692804.aspx

Comment: Last improvement, the script is working fine. After testing it i got a problem with the script, because some of the users dont have an email. So is there a way to skip the persons without having an email and maybe but it into a seperat output file?

Comment: @timo of course its possible, i wouldnt do it in a oneliner though. all you are asking is pretty basic so i would suggest you read up on powershell basics and do it yourself, this isnt hard

Answer (score 2):

Your command is about right. However, `Get-ADUser` doesn't seem to accept usernames in the [UPN or Down-Level Logon Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380525%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) formats.
To query a domain other than the one the current user is logged on, you need to use the `-Server` option. This option accepts either FQDN or NetBIOS domain names. 
Another thing: by default, `Get-ADUser` returns only the default properties set (see [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12037.active-directory-get-aduser-default-and-extended-properties.aspx) list to know the default properties), and a user's email address is not a default property, so we need to use the `-Properties` option to add it to the returned values.

The command would look like this:

```
$defaultDomain = $env:USERDOMAIN
$usersFilePath = C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Users.txt
Get-Content $usersFilePath | %{
    if ($_.Contains("\")) {
    @{username = $_.Split("\")[1]; server = $_.Split("\")[0]}
    } 
    elseif ($_.Contains("@")) {
        @{username = $_.Split("@")[0]; server = $_.Split("@")[1]}
    }
    else {
        @{username = $_; server = $defaultDomain}
    }
} | %{ Get-ADUser -Identity $_.username -Properties Mail -Server $_.server} | select -ExpandProperty mail
```

Comment: Great Informations u gave me. It is actually a bit to hard to read it for me. I should read more into the powershell functions.